# $(x+b)^3\mid P(x)+a$ and $(x-a)^3\mid P(x)-a$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

$a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, $b!=0$

I need to find all the polynomials $P$ of degree $5$ verifying:

$ \begin{cases}(x+b)^3\mid P(x)+a\\
(x-b)^3\mid P(x)-a\end{cases} $  PS : there was en error, i fixed it

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  $(x+b)^3|P(x)+a$ means $P(x)+a = (x+b)^3Q(x)$, with $Q$ quadratic.

Therefore

$$P(x)-a= (x+b)^3Q(x)-2a \,.$$

Now recall that for a Polynomial $H(x)$ you have $(x-a)^3|H(x)$ if and only if $H(a)=H'(a)=H''(a)=0$.

If you apply this to $H(x)=(x+b)^3Q(x)-2a$, you will find $Q(a), Q'(a)$ and $Q''(a)$. This is enough to find the Quadratic polynomial $Q(x)$.

Comment: I find H(a)=H'(a)=H''(a)=0 therefore (a+b)^3*Q(a)-2a=0, 3(a+b)^2*Q(a)+(a+b)^3*Q'(a)=0 and 6(a+b)Q(a)+Q'(a)*6(a+b)^2+(a+b)^3*Q''(a)=0  -> How do i get Q ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon  Let $Q(x)=\alpha x^2+ \beta x + \gamma$. Then $Q''(a)= 2 \alpha ; Q'(a)=2 \alpha a+ \beta ; Q(a)=\alpha a^2+ \beta a+ \gamma$. Plugging in into the equations you got gives you a system of equations in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$...